# When I try to handle error in mongoose.findOne it give me `Unhandled 'error' event`

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

## Mongoose unhandled 'error' event

When I try to handle errors in `mongoose.findOne()` function, I wanted to use second parameter like this `mongoose.findOne({ uuid: uuid }, (err,doc))` but can not see any error because of the following error :

> throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event

#### Here is my usage :

```js
  await endPointSchema.findOne({ uuid: uuid }, (err, doc) => {
    if (err) {
      res.status(403).json({ message: "Something went wrong!" });
      return;
    }
    
    if (!doc.endpoint) {
      const data = new endPointSchema({
        uuid: uuid,
        endpoint: [{ point: Endpoint, Content }],
        date: Date.now(),
      });
      data.save();
      res.status(200).json({ message: "Succesfully Created new Breakpoint" });
      return;
    }

    doc.endpoint = [...doc.endpoint, {Endpoint: Content}]
    doc.save()
    res.status(200).json({ message: "Succesfully Created new Breakpoint" });
    return
  });
```

### After first solution

### Now I get this error;

`(node:8140) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client     at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:561:11)     at ServerResponse.header (C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Nedim Akar\project-a server\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:771:10)     at ServerResponse.send (C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Nedim Akar\project-a server\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:170:12)`

### Here is my endpoint;

```js
route.post("/endpoint", AuthorizePanel, async (req, res) => {
  const { role, username, uuid } = req.user;
  if (!role && !username && !uuid) {
    res.sendStatus(401);
    return;
  }

  const { Endpoint, Content } = req.body;
  if (Endpoint === username) {
    res.status(403).json({ message: "Endpoint can not be same with your username!" });
    return;
  }

 try {
const doc = await endPointSchema.findOne({ uuid: uuid })
    if (!doc.endpoint) {
      const data = new endPointSchema({
        uuid: uuid,
        endpoint: [{ point: Endpoint, Content }],
        date: Date.now(),
      });
      await data.save();
      res.status(200).json({ message: "Succesfully Created new Breakpoint" });
      return;
    }

    doc.endpoint = [...doc.endpoint, {Endpoint: Content}]
    await doc.save()
    res.status(200).json({ message: "Succesfully Created new Breakpoint" });
    return
} catch(e) {
      res.status(403).json({ message: "Something went wrong!" });
}
});
```

What I use ?

- Express: `^4.17.1`
- Mongoose: `^5.12.14`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use async/await and callbacks at the same time. This is how you should refactor the code :

```
try {
const doc = await endPointSchema.findOne({ uuid: uuid })
    if (!doc.endpoint) {
      const data = new endPointSchema({
        uuid: uuid,
        endpoint: [{ point: Endpoint, Content }],
        date: Date.now(),
      });
      await data.save();
      res.status(200).json({ message: "Succesfully Created new Breakpoint" });
      return;
    }

    doc.endpoint = [...doc.endpoint, {Endpoint: Content}]
    await doc.save()
    res.status(200).json({ message: "Succesfully Created new Breakpoint" });
    return
} catch(e) {
      res.status(403).json({ message: "Something went wrong!" });
}
```

Comment: After I use your refacted code my error message is changed now it looks like this;
`(node:8140) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
    at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:561:11)
    at ServerResponse.header (C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Nedim Akar\project-a server\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:771:10)
    at ServerResponse.send (C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Nedim Akar\project-a server\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:170:12)`

Comment: But looks like everything is well with HTTP header

Comment: Mongoose `save()`  is asynchronous, so need to use `await` right?

Comment: Yes, it is async op.

Comment: Have you checked now? This errors comes when we send response twice to the user.

Comment: I checked but everythings is well

Comment: If that answer solves the problem, I request you to accept it and ask a new question for the error you are receiving now.